# Java counter not working correctly

Tags: java, loops, methods, counter

Below is my Java Code. If user Inputs a number which is not equal to `1` the method `getInput()` will be called again.

```
public void getInput(){
int i=0;
    while(i<=4){
        result[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Result (1 = pass, 2 = fail)"));
        int res = result[i];
        if(res!=1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong input, please try again!");
            System.out.println("Wrong Input:" + res);
            getInput();
        }
        System.out.println("count:"+i);
        i=i+1;
    }
}
```

Below are the results produce by the code

- count:0 <- Starts Counting from 0
- count:1
- Wrong Input:2 <- Enter wrong input and call method `getInput()` again.
- count:0 <- Starts Counting from 0
- count:1
- count:2
- count:3
- count:4
- count:2 <- Starts again from 2
- count:3
- count:4

The problem is that the counter is not working properly. Can someone please help me to fix this issue and why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `getInput()` from inside itself starts recursion. After a recursive method call is completed, the execution will resume at the calling site and (assuming there are no side effects) with the same state as right before the recursive call.

Therefore, if your user enters 2 you call `getInput()` recursively and as soon as this "inner" execution completes successfully (i.e. user entered 1 four times), the "inner" `getInput()` returns and the outer one resumes with exact the same state as before (your count variable is declared locally!).

I would suggest to not use recursion here, but a simpler if/else construct and alter the variable `i` to maintain state:

```
while (i <= 4) {
   // input code here
   if  (res != 1) {
      // fail message for user here
      i = 0;
   } else {
      // success message for user here
      i++;
   }
}
```

Note that this method may frustrate the user, an option to cancel the execution should be added (:

Comment: count:0
Wrong Input:
count:0
count:1
count:2
count:3
count:4
count:0
count:1
count:2
count:3
count:4 - These are the results i got when implemented the above code. The while loop runs twice.

Comment: did you remove the `getInput()` call in the if-condition? It looks like you are still recursing into your method.

Comment: Thanks Prynja!! removing the recursive call fixed the problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

Each time you call the method `getInput()` you set `i = 0`, try to pass the counter as a methods parameter:

```
public void getInput(int i){
    while(i<=4){
        result[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Result (1 = pass, 2 = fail)"));
        int res = result[i];
        if(res!=1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong input, please try again!");
            System.out.println("Wrong Input:" + res);
            getInput();
        }
        System.out.println("count:"+i);
        i=i+1;
    }
}
```

I would not use recursive calls for this purpose, why not do it like this:

```
public void getInput(){      
  while(i<=4) && ((res = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Result (1 = pass, 2 = fail)"))) != 1){        
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong input, please try again!");
      System.out.println("Wrong Input: " + res);          
      i = i + 1; 
    }
    System.out.println("count:" + i);        
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't fix the issue :( `getInput(0);` passed parameter value 0 to the method inside the if condition.

Comment: You need to increment the i before calling the function recursevley

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to fix this by removing the recursive call. Prynja asked to remove the recursive call first so i pick his one as the answer but don't worry I have +1 your answer. Your answer is neat ;)

Comment: @frozenhaart Do not worry, as long as you accept an answer i am happy :)